# How to pass null model to action method from an anchor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I use ASP.Core in my project. I have a link in sidebar menu that calls an action method from another controller.
The action method accepts a model:

```
 public IActionResult Search(MyVm myVm){....}
```

In my model I have a property that I want to set it with a default value in first load. I mean, The property called `StatusId` should be `123` in first load of the page, and later, should be set by user from view page.
I thought the solution is using a condition: if model(input) is null it means the page's loaded for first time (from sidebar menu), and the `StatusId` should be `123`, else use the `myVm.StatusId` value.
But I don't know how should I pass null to action method from the sidebar menu's link.

Comment: you can use in condition double quotation mark "" or giving the null keyword.

Comment: would you please explain it more?

Comment: Why not just set the value in the default constructor for you model?

Comment: since just in first time that my page is loading I have to use default value. in pagination status and submit the form, the value should be the user's input

Answer (score 0):

let I am doing code in c#,

```
if(model == null || model == "")
{
 StatusId = 123
}
else
{
 myVm.StatusId
}
```

Comment: no, the question is how to pass null as model from my anchor (in my sidebar menu) to  the action method. Then yes, you are correct, I will use a condition, above.